# Create a new row to assign M/F to a column based on heading, referencing second table?

Tags: r, database, rna-seq

I am new to R (and coding in general) and am really stuck on how to approach this problem.

I have a very large data set; columns are sample ID# (~7000 samples) and rows are gene expression (~20,000 genes). Column headings are `BIOPSY1-A`, `BIOPSY1-B`, `BIOPSY1-C`, ..., `BIOPSY200-Z`. Each number (1-200) is a different patient, and each sample for that patient is a different letter (-A, -Z).

I would like to do some comparisons between samples that came from men and women. Gender is not included in this gene expression table. I have a separate file with patient numbers (`BIOPSY1-200`) and their gender M/F.

I would like to code something that will look at the column ID (ex: `BIOPSY7-A`), recognize that it includes "BIOPSY7" (but not == BIOPSY7 because there is `BIOPSY7-A` through `BIOPSY7-Z`), find "BIOPSY7" in the reference file, extrapolate M/F, and create a new row with M/F designation.

Honestly, I am so overwhelmed with coding this that I tried to open the file in Excel to manually input M/F, for the 7000 columns as it would probably be faster. However, the file is so large that Excel crashes when it opens.

Any input or resources that would put me on the right path would be extremely appreciated!!

Comment: Hi Desert007. Could you kindly provide a sample dataset of the same structure as your dataset. By reproducing your structure, it is easier for the community to help you. By sample dataset, I simply mean the code of generating it. On another note, if you are encountering memory issues in R (for future reference), I can recommend data.table fread() for reading files, and the fst file format for local storage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know how your data looks like, so I made mine based on your definitions. I'm sure you can modify this answer based on your needs and your dataset structure:

```
library(data.table)
genderfile <-data.frame("ID"=c("BIOPSY1", "BIOPSY2", "BIOPSY3", "BIOPSY4", "BIOPSY5"),"Gender"=c("F","M","M","F","M"))

#you can just read in your gender file to r with the line below
#genderfile <- read.csv("~/gender file.csv")
    View(genderfile)
```

[image]

```
df<-matrix(rnorm(45, mean=10, sd=5),nrow=3)
colnames(df)<-c("BIOPSY1-A", "BIOPSY1-B", "BIOPSY1-C", "BIOPSY2-A", "BIOPSY2-B", "BIOPSY2-C","BIOPSY3-A", "BIOPSY3-B", "BIOPSY3-C","BIOPSY4-A", "BIOPSY4-B", "BIOPSY4-C","BIOPSY5-A", "BIOPSY5-B", "BIOPSY5-C")
df<-cbind(Gene=seq(1:3),df)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
#you can just read in your main df to r with the line below, fread prevents dashes to turn to period in r, you need data.table package installed and checked in 
#df<-fread("~/first file.csv")
View(df)
```

[image]

Note that the following line of code removes the dash and letter from the column names of df (I removed the first column by df[,-c(1)] because it is the Gene id):

```
substr(x=names(df[,-c(1)]),start=1,stop=nchar(names(df[,-c(1)]))-2)
#[1] "BIOPSY1" "BIOPSY1" "BIOPSY1" "BIOPSY2" "BIOPSY2" "BIOPSY2" "BIOPSY3" "BIOPSY3" "BIOPSY3" "BIOPSY4" "BIOPSY4"
#[12] "BIOPSY4" "BIOPSY5" "BIOPSY5" "BIOPSY5"
```

Now, we are ready to match the columns of df with the ID in genderfile to get the Gender column:

```
Gender<-genderfile[, "Gender"][match(substr(x=names(df[,-c(1)]),start=1,stop=nchar(names(df[,-c(1)]))-2), genderfile[,"ID"])]
Gender
 #[1] F F F M M M M M M F F F M M M
```

Last step is to add the Gender defined above as a row to the df:

```
df_withGender<-rbind(c("Gender", as.character(Gender)), df)
View(df_withGender)
```

[image]